# how to convert csv file to binary file using google protocol buffer in C++

Tags: visual-c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

I had studied it, conceptually I have a basic knowledge but practically I am finding it difficult. I am finding difficult in importing the library, I am new to this, so how to convert the csv file into binary file using google protocol buffer in C++

Comment: Could you define "Conver csv file to Binary file"? In general, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i have a csv file , i want to convert it into a binary file using c++ and i am told to use google protobuf, its a task.

Comment: Sorry I was quite busy. I still need some more information. It is hard to give you any advice since it is specific to your project. Did you try to read some documentation? I think  https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/cpptutorial
would be a good start for you. If you have any additional questions regarding specifically C++, post them here, or open  a new thread.